# Custom file format in Impala

Tags: impala

We have a custom internal data format. I'd like to use Impala with this format, just for reading. I want to write the binding for this format. But there is no reason to contribute this back, as nobody else uses this format.

Does Impala support file format plugins in some way?

From [`hdfs-scan-node.cc`](https://github.com/cloudera/Impala/blob/cdh5-2.3.0_5.5.0/be/src/exec/hdfs-scan-node.cc#L264) it looks like the list of file formats is hardcoded unfortunately. If this is the case, is there a plan to change this? Or is this not a common problem for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as stated in [How Impala Works with Hadoop File Formats](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_file_formats.html#file_formats):

> Impala can only query the file formats listed in the preceding table. In particular, Impala does not support the ORC file format.

The reasons for this are probably related to the run-time code generation which would be harder to optimize if Impala didn't constrain file formats.
However, Impala is an open source project and there is no reason why you cannot suggest this by filing a JIRA.

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/02/inside-cloudera-impala-runtime-code-generation/
https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/IMPALA/issues
https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_file_formats.html